# pop-up does not close, but is white

Tags: fix-my-code, content, component-params, popup

I tried several plugins and no one was able to load (inside the popup) the web page I wanted i.e. http://www.nicovon.joomlafree.it/sala_camino.html

this [testing site](http://www.nicovon.joomlafree.it/galleria-virtual-tour.html)
is, instead, the site where I'm doing these tests. by clicking on the link at the bottom (Click on me!) or by clicking on the first photo, should open (inside a popup), the web page that I wrote in the link above.

Update. the pop-up appears to be widening to the correct size, it does not close, but is white.

Comment: Rather than trying to load the web page, perhaps try copying the html from that page into one of the plugins that you have tried. It's hard to give you any more advice than that based on the information you have provided. For example, https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/simple-pop-up/  would allow you to put the html into a module then load it in the popup. Alternatively you could put the html into an article and load it that way. I can't vouch for this plugin by the way. It was simply the first one I found.

Comment: this thing is very interesting!. Thank you so much. right now I'm using the "modals" plugin made by regular labs. it is much easier to use than what you have recommended to me, however, it provides a free version or a pro version. I'm using the free version and I do not know if I can do with the free version.

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be more than 1 problem with your example page.
1. you specify the href of the popup link as /www.etc but you want //www.etc
2. the pano2yr player js fails to load even if you fix the href.  You can see that in your console.

Comment: I modified the code this way: `{modal url="phocapanorama/output/sala_camino.html"}Click on me!{/modal}`. Now a popup opens but is blank, and continues to load endlessly.

Comment: why js script fails to load? How can I see logs?

Comment: Ok.  You need to focus on the difference between absolute and relative links.  Your js fails to load because you are calling like this: <script type="text/javascript" src="pano2vr_player.js"> and then embedding that page on a different page using the modal box so that js attempts to load from http://www.nicovon.joomlafree.it/pano2vr_player.js which just 404s.  Either switch your modal box to use an iframe or change the src attribute in the js call to be absolute.  To see errors open the devtools panel in chrome and you will see the error.

Comment: thank you! good advice! the console is very useful! I changed the path of pano2vr_player.js and skin.js, but now I am faced with another error: `GET http://www.nicovon.joomlafree.it/images/autorotate.svg 404 (View not found [name, type, prefix]: category, svg, contentView)`. This means I have to change the skin.js file like this: `this._up__img.setAttribute ('src', basePath + 'phocapanorama/output/images/up.svg');` instead of `this._up__img.setAttribute ('src', basePath + 'images/up.svg');` I made this change to all svg I found in the file, but the same error continues to occur.

Comment: all resolved. evidently the changes to the file had not yet been updated. next time I will not use the "ProFiles" editor. back to the main problem, the console does not show significant errors: `[.CommandBufferContext]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.` and as you can see, the pop-up closes and opens a blank page. absurd!

Comment: I'm sorry! I was using Chrome on Windows XP (version 49.0.2623.112 m). then I moved on a PC with a newer version of chrome and the result is a little different, ie the pop-up appears to be widening to the correct size, it does not close, but is white, again!

Comment: I update you with the changes I just made. first of all, I moved "sala_camino.html" in the root directory. (This way the scripts are loaded properly). then I added a pop-up using the other plugin: `{modal url="sala_camino.html"}popup made with modals{/modal}
{simplepopup name=vtpop popup=false url="sala_camino.html"}{/simplepopup} {simplepopup link=vtpop}popup made with simplepopup{/simplepopup}`. if I click on the second link, then close it and I click on the first, everything works. why?